# How to access a field that is always in the same position, but has a different name?

Tags: python, json

I am playing around with some soccer matchdata that is in JSON format, saved in the variable "matches" via

```
with open('path') as json_data:
    matches = json.load(json_data)
```

The following is an excerpt of the data for match number 1 (gained via "matches[1]":

```
{
  "status": "Played",
  "roundId": 4405517,
  "gameweek": 34,
  "teamsData": {
    "2482": {
      "scoreET": 0,
      "coachId": 272299,
      "side": "home",
      "teamId": 2482,
      "score": 3,
      "scoreP": 0,
      "hasFormation": 1,
      "formation": {
        "bench": [
```

The name of the field "2482" is the ID of one of the two teams playing in the match (the other one follows later, but providing the whole match data for for even one match would make this post far too long). The data goes on like this (306 matches, 2 teams each), i. e. the field is always in the same position in the data. Since the field's name is always different, however, I am struggling to access it for e.g. game number 20 without looking up the team's ID first since

```
match[20]['teamsData'][1]
```

does not work ("KeyError: 1").

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You can't directly index the values of a `dict`. Try: `list(match[20]['teamsData'].values())[0]`

Comment: Do note that, according to the JSON specification, implementations of JSON may or may not preserve key ordering of objects. Python's implementation seems to respect it, but whoever is generating these JSON files may not.

Comment: `match[20]['teamsData']` is a `dict`. How many keys does it have? Is it just that one team? Or perhaps the two teams with one being "home" and the other something else?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I am not sure I understand the consequences of that. Do you mean that in the JSON, the key ordering might be rather random but python just sorts it nicely so that it always looks the same?

Comment: @tdelaney it has two keys, one for the home team, one for the away team. What I would like to do (and should be able to do with quamrana's solution) is to go through all 306 matches and extract the respective team data (e. g. coachId, score, the data that follows after "bench:").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a dictionary as an index, and in your case you could just reindex the data with a more convenient value. If "side" is always either "home" or "away", you can use that known value instead of the variable team id value.

In this example, "teamsData" is replaced with a reindexed dictionary.

```
for match in matches:
    match["teamsData"] = {value["side"]:value for value in match["teamsData"].values()}

matches[20]["teamData"]["home"]
```